# Check for $.ajax html result being empty

Tags: jquery

I want to know if the html returned in the success callback is empty:

```
var url = "..."
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
        if(html === ""){
             alert("empty");
        }
    }
});
```

But this does not work for me. Any ideas?

Comment: u used the = sign three times ... just in case...

Comment: with == it does not work too :)

Comment: using `===` is very *good* idea in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your particular example, the `success` handler would never get fired anyway.

You should bind an `error handler` aswell:

```
var url = "..."
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
        alert('suc');
        if(!$.trim(html).length){
             alert("empty");
        }
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('err');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
success: function(html){
    if($.trim(html) === ""){
         alert("empty");
    }
}
```